# Creating a DropDownList reading directly from a table (ASP.NET MVC CORE & c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, dropdownlistfor

Need a little help in here.

I want to create a drop down list and be able to display all the different values of a single row (in this case, a dropdown list containing emails); i am reading directly from a SQL SERVER table:

I created a **Model cs file** called DropDownList and it contains:

```
public class Email{
    public string Email { get; set}

}
```

I did this function in order to get all the values stored in that table:

```
public IEnumerable<Emails> GetEmailList()
{
    var emailList = new List<Emails>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetEmailValues", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {

            var listEmail = new Emails();
            listEmail.Email = dr["Email"].ToString();

            emailList.Add(listEmail);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    return emailList;
}
```

This is my **controller file**:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Emails> emailList = dbContext.GetEmailList().ToList();
    return View(emailList);
}
```

This is my **HTML file**:

```
@model Application.Models

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>EDIT</h1>

<h4>Edit</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I do not understand what should i do in order to get that DROPDOWNLIST, been reading different things but no one really helped me. Can help me?

---

EDIT:

I would like to obtain something like this:

[image]

Comment: Your class is `DropDownList`,So what are your `Emails`?

Comment: Hey pal, thanks for replying.
Sorry, my Model cs file is called "Email" too. I have updated my thread

Comment: In which views do you want to display the drop-down list?

Comment: I want to display it in my edit view, do you get me?, i need a field called email and there i should be able to select the desired mail

Comment: Can you share your edit method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asp-items` taghelper:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
  ViewData["Email1"] = new SelectList(dbContext.GetEmailList().ToList(), "Email", "Email");
   ViewData["Email2"] = new SelectList(//your selected list ,"Email", "Email");
  return View();
}
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(string email1,string email2)
    {
        //your code.
        return View();
    }
```

Edit View:

```
@model DropDownList

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="email1" asp-items="ViewBag.Email1"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="email2" asp-items="ViewBag.Email2"></select>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hey pal. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Hi @programming_amazing,does this answer solve your problem?

Comment: Pal, i would like to put your **ActionResult Edit** but in my **ActionResult Index()** instead, would it be the same, right?

Comment: Yes,you can try

Comment: Pal, in your view file, how could it be possible to DUPLICATE the same field that contains all the different emails from the database?
I mean: i would like to display two times the same dropdownlist and it should say "Select the first email: and the second one "Select the second email". Am i clear?

Comment: Hi @programming_amazing, Do you mean something like the picture in my updated answer? Or other needs?

Comment: I mean, in your application you are only getting just a single dropdown list but i would like to display 2  because i want the user to select the email he already has and in the second one he should select the new email that he wants to use.

Comment: Hi @programming_amazing,Can't you create a new drop-down list in the same way?

Comment: Take a look, i have edited my thread. I'm a little confused because i do not fully understand how should i save both values that were selected by the user in the EDIT view

Comment: Hi @programming_amazing,see my updated answer.

Comment: You rock!. Last question: is there exist any attribute that could allow me to give every dropdown list a name? like i did in my example (picture)?

Comment: Hi @programming_amazing,`<select name="email1" asp-items="ViewBag.Email">
                            <option>email1</option>
                        </select>`